# Undefined index: file

Tags: php, oop

I am getting the undefined index error as I come for the first time in my upload form page or if I move to next page and click on back button then I have the same error message.
If I upload a file then it works fine and the error message gets away.

I have also tried this:

```
global $file;
if (!isset($file)) {
    $file = '';
}
```

Here is my code:

```
<form id="uploadForm" name="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data"/>
  <fieldset>
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000" />
    <input type="file" name="file" />
<?php
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($_REQUEST['file']);
echo '</pre>';

$uploaded = new upload;
//set Max Size
$uploaded->set_max_size(350000);
//Set Directory
$uploaded->set_directory("data");
//Set Temp Name for upload.
$uploaded->set_tmp_name($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
//Set file size
$uploaded->set_file_size($_FILES['file']['size']);
//set file type
$uploaded->set_file_type($_FILES['file']['type']);
//set file name
$uploaded->set_file_name($_FILES['file']['name']);
//start copy process
$uploaded->start_copy();
if($uploaded->is_ok()) 
    echo " upload is doen.";
else
    $uploaded->error()."<br>";
?>
    <div class="filesize">JPG minimaal 800x60 pixels max. 2Mb</div>
    <a href="" class="submit" title="Upload your own phooto"><span> Upload your own photo </span></a>
```

upload_inc.php

```
<?
class upload
{
    var $directory_name;
    var $max_filesize;
    var $error;

    var $user_tmp_name;
    var $user_file_name;
    var $user_file_size;
    var $user_file_type;
    var $user_full_name;

    function set_directory($dir_name =".")
    {
        $this->directory_name = $dir_name;
    }

    function set_max_size($max_file = 2000000)
    {
        $this->max_filesize = $max_file;
    }

    function error()
    {
        return $this->error;
    }

    function is_ok()
    {
        if(isset($this->error))
            return FALSE;
        else
            return TRUE;
    }

    function set_tmp_name($temp_name)
    {
        $this->user_tmp_name = $temp_name;
    }

    function set_file_size($file_size)
    {
         $this->user_file_size = $file_size;
    }

    function set_file_type($file_type)
    {
        $this->user_file_type = $file_type;
    }

    function set_file_name($file)
    {
        $this->user_file_name = $file;
        $this->user_full_name = $this->directory_name."/".$this->user_file_name;
    }

    function start_copy()
    {
        if(!isset($this->user_file_name))
            $this->error = "You must define filename!";
        if ($this->user_file_size <= 0)
            $this->error = 'File size error (0):' . $this->user_file_size . 'KB <br>';
        if ($this->user_file_size > $this->max_filesize)
            $this->error = 'File size error (1):' . $this->user_file_size . 'KB<br>';
        if($this->user_file_type != "image/jpeg")
            $this->error = "the image must be jpeg extension";
        if (!isset($this->error))
        {
            $filename = basename($this->user_file_name);
            if (!empty($this->directory_name))
                $destination = $this->user_full_name;
            else
                $destination = $filename;
            if(!is_uploaded_file($this->user_tmp_name))
                $this->error = "File " . $this->user_tmp_name . " is not uploaded correctly.";
            if (!move_uploaded_file ($this->user_tmp_name,$destination))
                $this->error = "Impossible to copy " . $this->user_file_name . " from your folder to destination directory.";
        }
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful and descriptive title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`"Undefined index"` means you're trying to read an array element that doesn't exist.

Your specific problem seems to be that you're trying to read upload data that doesn't exist yet: When you first visit your upload form, there is no `$_FILES` array (or rather, there's nothing in it), because the form hasn't been submitted. But since you don't check if the form was submitted, these lines net you an error:

```
//Set Temp Name for upload.
$uploaded->set_tmp_name($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
//Set file size
$uploaded->set_file_size($_FILES['file']['size']);
//set file type
$uploaded->set_file_type($_FILES['file']['type']);
//set file name
$uploaded->set_file_name($_FILES['file']['name']);
```

They're all trying to read the value of `$_FILES['file']` to pass them to the methods of `$uploaded`.

What you need is a check beforehand:

```
if (isset($_FILES['file'])) {
    $uploaded = new upload;
    //set Max Size
    $uploaded->set_max_size(350000);
    //Set Directory
    $uploaded->set_directory("data");
    //Set Temp Name for upload.
    $uploaded->set_tmp_name($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
    //Set file size
    $uploaded->set_file_size($_FILES['file']['size']);
    //set file type
    $uploaded->set_file_type($_FILES['file']['type']);
    //set file name
    $uploaded->set_file_name($_FILES['file']['name']);
    //start copy process
    $uploaded->start_copy();
    if($uploaded->is_ok()) 
        echo " upload is doen.";
    else
        $uploaded->error()."<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is probably in your upload class. The error message is pretty clear, if that is the actual message you get there is probably a line somewhere in that class that looks for an array key I that is named 'fileUpload'.

Just do a search in your code for 'fileUpload', and add something to check if the key is set, ie

```
 if(isset($arraywhatever['fileUpload'])) condition to your code.
```

Comment: the actual error is: Undefined index: file in /var/www/www.test.org/site/step5.php on line 71. It does not recognize the [file] and shows error for all lines where i have [file] the name of my input. could you help plz

Comment: just do vardump($_REQUEST); insead of print_r($_FILES['file']);  This will show you all your set $_POST variable. Also , remove the uneeded action="" in the form tag if it is posting to itself and  make sure your fieldset tag is closed. I don't think you posted the whole script so it's hard to see what is wrong.

Comment: i am getting the same error msg Undefined index: file in /var/www/www.test.org/site/step5.php on line 71

Comment: i have all mijn two pages code copied in my original msg. There are two pages upload_inc.php & form.php