# Notice: Undefined index: image in

Tags: php, database, upload, xampp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Undefined index: file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6098261/undefined-index-file)

Hi I'm learning right now how to upload images to database, but I'm getting this error/notice

> Notice: Undefined index: image in C:\xampp\htdocs\Pildibaas\index.php on line 19

Here is my index.php whole code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Image upload</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="index.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        File:
        <input type="file" name="image"> <input type="submit" value="Upload"> 
    </form>


<?php
mysql_connect ("localhost", "root", "") or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db ("databaseimage") or die (mysql_error());


?>
</body>

</html>
```

Line 19 (this line gives error) cut out from index.php:

```
echo $file = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
```

From google found that i need to change premission of tmp folder, but it allready shoud have all premissions it needs.

In tutorial he dont get this error

thank you

Comment: You have 2 times an document in the code... Is this realy what you have? or is copy space gone wrong???

Comment: and now you have the echo line not in the code...

Comment: Just change your form to include enctype="multipart/form-data" like                                                    
                                    <form method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
echo $file = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
```

should be

```
if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
    echo $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
}
```

This checks first if `$_FILES['image']` is set. If not, this wil not be run. Therefore, you will not have an error that it is out of index.

Because you first have to submit the form before `$_FILES['image']` will be set...

Also, the input tag is self closing, so your form will not be:

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    File:
    <input type="file" name="image"> <input type="submit" value="Upload"> 
</form>
```

but:

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    File:
    <input type="file" name="image" /> <input type="submit" value="Upload" /> 
</form>
```

Comment: Yes, thank you that fix error/notice. But souldnt it upload something into tmp folder? So if i would do something like `echo $image = file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])` i would get echod out lot of rubish and symbols.

Comment: @user1203497, afcourse you get a lot of rubisch. first youve got to move the file to somewhere: `move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $newDirForImage);` and then youve got to echo the url in an image tag: `echo '<img src="'.$newDirForImage.$fileName.'" />';`

Hope you understand what i mean...

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $file = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
```

should be

```
echo $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
 or 
if(!empty($_FILES) && isset($_FILES['image'])){
  echo $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    }
```

you can also use

```
print_r($_FILES);
```